# Rust tonic avoiding shared resources

Tags: rust, rust-tonic

I don't have much experience with Tonic (or Rust) and I'm trying to figure out the correct pattern for setting up a service. Basically, I have the following code:

```
Server::builder()
    .add_service(MyService::new(some_resource))
    .serve(addr)
    .await?;
```

Now the problem with this setup is that MyService must be `Send` and `Sync`, which places restrictions on `some_resource`.

In my current case, `some_resource` is an RSA key from the `tink-core` crate. More specifically, what's returned by the following:

https://github.com/project-oak/tink-rust/blob/main/signature/src/verifier_factory.rs#L23

There's really no reason to have a shared resource here, which would cause lock contention. I could just as well have a thread-local RSA key. In other words, how could I use a `tink_core::Verifier` instance inside a Tonic service without having to protect it by a lock?

Comment: Why would you need a lock?

Comment: Don't I need to package it up into Arc<Mutex<...>> to make it Send and Sync? Sorry I'm also quite new to Rust.

Comment: I was thinking it didn't have any mutable methods so there's no reason for a `Mutex` (to get a `&mut self`), but looking at it again, if a function returning `Box<dyn Verifier>` is your source then not even `Arc` and `Mutex` will help. An object requires `Send` or `Sync` to be used across threads and `Box<dyn Verifier>` has neither specified.

Comment: Ok, so how can this be made to work then?

Comment: One idea that I had was to just include the raw RSA key as a string in MyService, then create an instance of ThreadLocal into the MyService and have a signature verification method that then constructs the think_core::Verifier and puts it into the ThreadLocal. However, getting stuck with that too...